# Update Cursor - Removing Strings/keywords

Tags: arcpy, cursor, mosaic-dataset

I have a mosaic data (over 500k rows) I want to run a UpdateCursor on to clean up a string field which roughly follows this pattern:

```
1432 Arequipa 92 PRINCIPAL SAT CAPTURE
2235 Pokhara 11 SECONDARY AERIAL PROGRAM
```

I want to end up with:

```
Arequipa 92
Pokhara 11
```

My attempt -

```
import arcpy

#get mosaic dataset layer
md = r"C:\...Mosaic"
mdl = arcpy.MakeMosaicLayer_management(md, "md_layer")

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(mdl,['FIELD']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        try:
            fstrip = row[0][5:]
            rep1 = fstrip.replace("PRINCIPAL","")
            rep2 = rep1.replace("SAT","")
            rep3 = rep2.replace("CAPTURE","")
            rep4 = rep3.replace("PROGRAM","")
            rep5 = rep4.replace("SECONDARY","")
            rep6 = rep6.replace("AERIAL","")
            row[0] = rep6
            print(rep6)
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        except Exception:
            pass
```

This is obviously super inefficient - any tips to do a multiple replace while working around the immutability of the objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont think your code should be very inefficient, but you can shorten it.

If the field/string always have the words/numbers you want to extract in index 1 and 2, you can convert it to a list using split, extract index 1 and 2 with itemgetter and join back to a string with join:

```
import arcpy
from operator import itemgetter

mdl = "some_layer"

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(mdl,['FIELD']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = ' '.join(itemgetter(1,2)(row[0].split()))
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```